# How to set default column renderer by column type in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, grid, cell, extjs4.2, renderer

I've a grid in ExtJS 4.2 and I need to set default renderer for its columns by type. It means that I've a renderer function for each grid column type (a renderer for `Boolean` columns, another for `Date` columns, another for `Number` columns, etc) and I want to change default renderer by column type globally (I can't set it individually for each grid column because I can't change legacy code).
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this override for boolean column and same this code for other column type :

```
Ext.define('MyBooleanColumn',{
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Boolean',
    renderer:function(v){
       // write your own customization code here
       return v;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just some links:
- [Best practice for overwriting classes properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254321/best-practice-for-overriding-classes-properties-in-extjs)
- [Steps to overriding Sencha ExtJS standard component functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249715/steps-to-overriding-sencha-extjs-standard-component-functionality-ext-tree-pane) 
- [Overriding Extjs classes and invoking callParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898565/overriding-extjs-classes-and-invoking-callparent)
You should overwrite the [Boolean column type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Boolean) (and other also) once and it (they) will be used everywhere.